# Eigenvector Approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, perturbation-theory

Consider symmetric matrices $A$ and $E$ (both with dimensions $n \times n$), and let $\hat{A} = A + E$. If $\mathbf{u_1}$ is the eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $A$ (denoted as $\lambda_1$), then we can approximate $\mathbf{\hat{u}_1}$ (the eigenvector of $\hat{A}$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of  $\hat{A}$) as:
$$ \mathbf{\hat{u}_1} \approx  \mathbf{u_1} + \sum_{i = 2}^n \frac{\mathbf{u_i}^t  E \ \mathbf{u_1}}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_i}\mathbf{u_i} $$

In my coursework we were simply told this is a first order approximation, but I would like to know how this equation is derived. Additionally, I am aware that the equation holds for small $\|E\|$ but isn't this relative to the size of $n$? It would seem that the accuracy of the approximation is a function of how large $\|E\|$ is relative to $n$ and not simply how large $\|E\|$ is (considering that the elements of the normalized eigenvectors $\mathbf{u_i}$ would get increasingly smaller).

Comment: [Here is a derivation](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~ldeldebb/docs/QM/lect17.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding the document as I'm not very familiar with quantum mechanics. Would it be too much to bother you for a translation of sorts?

Answer (score 1):

It is not specifically about QM, it is just perturbation of matrices. In your notation, consider $A+\epsilon E$ and *assume* the eigenvalues and eigenvectors have Taylor expansions in $\epsilon$. Plug the expansions into the eigenvector equation $(A+\epsilon E)u(\epsilon)=\lambda(\epsilon)u(\epsilon)$, take the indicated inner product, and equate coefficients of $\epsilon$.